# RubberDuck Parse Error on Initial Refresh

Tags: rubberduck

I installed RubberDuck and opened an Access 2007 Database I use as a code testing ground. When I click Refresh on the RD toolbar, the text continued to say `Pending`. After several click on the refresh button I open `Settings` and unchecked/Rechecked a random checkbox and clicked `Ok`. At that point my Refresh Button text showed `Parse Error`.

I then closed all instances of MS Access and re-opened the database. I changed the minimum logging level to `INFO`, and clicked the Refresh Button.

I do have an error in my log, but the Refresh Button still says `Pending`.

**Rubberducklog.txt:**

```
2017-10-26 11:10:35.3473;INFO-2.1.1.2431;Rubberduck.Common.LogLevelHelper;
    Rubberduck version 2.1.1.2431 loading:
    Operating System: Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 x86
    Host Product: 2007 Microsoft Office system x86
    Host Version: 12.0.6423.1000
    Host Executable: MSACCESS.EXE;
2017-10-26 11:10:35.7613;INFO-2.1.1.2431;Rubberduck.UI.Command.VersionCheckCommand;Executing version check.;
2017-10-26 11:10:58.7656;INFO-2.1.1.2431;Rubberduck.Parsing.VBA.RubberduckParserState;RubberduckParserState (1) is invoking StateChanged (Pending);
2017-10-26 11:10:58.7746;ERROR-2.1.1.2431;Rubberduck.Parsing.VBA.ParseCoordinator;Unexpected exception thrown in parsing run. (thread 5).;System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'Microsoft.Office.Core.CommandBarControl'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{000C0308-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}' failed due to the following error: Library not registered. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002801D (TYPE_E_LIBNOTREGISTERED)).
   at System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.GetCOMIPFromRCW(Object objSrc, IntPtr pCPCMD, IntPtr& ppTarget, Boolean& pfNeedsRelease)
   at Microsoft.Office.Core.CommandBarControl.set_Enabled(Boolean pvarfEnabled)
   at Rubberduck.VBEditor.SafeComWrappers.Office.Core.CommandBarControl.set_IsEnabled(Boolean value) in C:\projects\rubberduck\Rubberduck.VBEEditor\SafeComWrappers\Office.Core\CommandBarControl.cs:line 39
   at Rubberduck.UI.Command.MenuItems.CommandBars.AppCommandBarBase.EvaluateCanExecute(RubberduckParserState state) in C:\projects\rubberduck\RetailCoder.VBE\UI\Command\MenuItems\CommandBars\AppCommandBarBase.cs:line 124
   at Rubberduck.UI.Command.MenuItems.CommandBars.RubberduckCommandBar.OnParserStateChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\projects\rubberduck\RetailCoder.VBE\UI\Command\MenuItems\CommandBars\RubberduckCommandBar.cs:line 90
   at System.EventHandler`1.Invoke(Object sender, TEventArgs e)
   at Rubberduck.Parsing.VBA.RubberduckParserState.OnStateChanged(Object requestor, ParserState state) in C:\projects\rubberduck\Rubberduck.Parsing\VBA\RubberduckParserState.cs:line 331
   at Rubberduck.Parsing.VBA.RubberduckParserState.SetStatusAndFireStateChanged(Object requestor, ParserState status) in C:\projects\rubberduck\Rubberduck.Parsing\VBA\RubberduckParserState.cs:line 555
   at Rubberduck.Parsing.VBA.ParserStateManagerBase.SetStatusAndFireStateChanged(Object requestor, ParserState status, CancellationToken token) in C:\projects\rubberduck\Rubberduck.Parsing\VBA\ParserStateManagerBase.cs:line 51
   at Rubberduck.Parsing.VBA.ParseCoordinator.ParseAllInternal(Object requestor, CancellationToken token) in C:\projects\rubberduck\Rubberduck.Parsing\VBA\ParseCoordinator.cs:line 330
   at Rubberduck.Parsing.VBA.ParseCoordinator.ParseAll(Object requestor, CancellationToken token) in C:\projects\rubberduck\Rubberduck.Parsing\VBA\ParseCoordinator.cs:line 303
2017-10-26 11:10:59.1217;INFO-2.1.1.2431;Rubberduck.Parsing.VBA.RubberduckParserState;RubberduckParserState (2) is invoking StateChanged (Error);
```

**Revised to include error log from MS Excel 2010:**

```
2017-10-26 12:17:41.2597;INFO-2.1.1.2431;Rubberduck.Common.LogLevelHelper;
    Rubberduck version 2.1.1.2431 loading:
    Operating System: Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 x86
    Host Product: Microsoft Office 2010 x86
    Host Version: 14.0.7188.5000
    Host Executable: EXCEL.EXE;
2017-10-26 12:17:41.8027;INFO-2.1.1.2431;Rubberduck.UI.Command.VersionCheckCommand;Executing version check.;
2017-10-26 12:17:42.2597;INFO-2.1.1.2431;Rubberduck.Parsing.VBA.RubberduckParserState;RubberduckParserState (1) is invoking StateChanged (Pending);
2017-10-26 12:17:42.2737;ERROR-2.1.1.2431;Rubberduck.Parsing.VBA.ParseCoordinator;Unexpected exception thrown in parsing run. (thread 6).;System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'Microsoft.Office.Core.CommandBarControl'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{000C0308-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}' failed due to the following error: Library not registered. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002801D (TYPE_E_LIBNOTREGISTERED)).
   at System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.GetCOMIPFromRCW(Object objSrc, IntPtr pCPCMD, IntPtr& ppTarget, Boolean& pfNeedsRelease)
   at Microsoft.Office.Core.CommandBarControl.set_Enabled(Boolean pvarfEnabled)
   at Rubberduck.VBEditor.SafeComWrappers.Office.Core.CommandBarControl.set_IsEnabled(Boolean value) in C:\projects\rubberduck\Rubberduck.VBEEditor\SafeComWrappers\Office.Core\CommandBarControl.cs:line 39
   at Rubberduck.UI.Command.MenuItems.CommandBars.AppCommandBarBase.EvaluateCanExecute(RubberduckParserState state) in C:\projects\rubberduck\RetailCoder.VBE\UI\Command\MenuItems\CommandBars\AppCommandBarBase.cs:line 124
   at Rubberduck.UI.Command.MenuItems.CommandBars.RubberduckCommandBar.OnParserStateChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\projects\rubberduck\RetailCoder.VBE\UI\Command\MenuItems\CommandBars\RubberduckCommandBar.cs:line 90
   at System.EventHandler`1.Invoke(Object sender, TEventArgs e)
   at Rubberduck.Parsing.VBA.RubberduckParserState.OnStateChanged(Object requestor, ParserState state) in C:\projects\rubberduck\Rubberduck.Parsing\VBA\RubberduckParserState.cs:line 331
   at Rubberduck.Parsing.VBA.RubberduckParserState.SetStatusAndFireStateChanged(Object requestor, ParserState status) in C:\projects\rubberduck\Rubberduck.Parsing\VBA\RubberduckParserState.cs:line 555
   at Rubberduck.Parsing.VBA.ParserStateManagerBase.SetStatusAndFireStateChanged(Object requestor, ParserState status, CancellationToken token) in C:\projects\rubberduck\Rubberduck.Parsing\VBA\ParserStateManagerBase.cs:line 51
   at Rubberduck.Parsing.VBA.ParseCoordinator.ParseAllInternal(Object requestor, CancellationToken token) in C:\projects\rubberduck\Rubberduck.Parsing\VBA\ParseCoordinator.cs:line 330
   at Rubberduck.Parsing.VBA.ParseCoordinator.ParseAll(Object requestor, CancellationToken token) in C:\projects\rubberduck\Rubberduck.Parsing\VBA\ParseCoordinator.cs:line 303
2017-10-26 12:17:42.8447;INFO-2.1.1.2431;Rubberduck.Parsing.VBA.RubberduckParserState;RubberduckParserState (2) is invoking StateChanged (Error);
2017-10-26 12:17:56.3117;INFO-2.1.1.2431;Rubberduck.Parsing.VBA.RubberduckParserState;RubberduckParserState (3) is invoking StateChanged (Pending);
2017-10-26 12:17:56.3117;ERROR-2.1.1.2431;Rubberduck.Parsing.VBA.ParseCoordinator;Unexpected exception thrown in parsing run. (thread 7).;System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'Microsoft.Office.Core.CommandBarControl'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{000C0308-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}' failed due to the following error: Library not registered. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002801D (TYPE_E_LIBNOTREGISTERED)).
   at System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.GetCOMIPFromRCW(Object objSrc, IntPtr pCPCMD, IntPtr& ppTarget, Boolean& pfNeedsRelease)
   at Microsoft.Office.Core.CommandBarControl.set_Enabled(Boolean pvarfEnabled)
   at Rubberduck.VBEditor.SafeComWrappers.Office.Core.CommandBarControl.set_IsEnabled(Boolean value) in C:\projects\rubberduck\Rubberduck.VBEEditor\SafeComWrappers\Office.Core\CommandBarControl.cs:line 39
   at Rubberduck.UI.Command.MenuItems.CommandBars.AppCommandBarBase.EvaluateCanExecute(RubberduckParserState state) in C:\projects\rubberduck\RetailCoder.VBE\UI\Command\MenuItems\CommandBars\AppCommandBarBase.cs:line 124
   at Rubberduck.UI.Command.MenuItems.CommandBars.RubberduckCommandBar.OnParserStateChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\projects\rubberduck\RetailCoder.VBE\UI\Command\MenuItems\CommandBars\RubberduckCommandBar.cs:line 90
   at System.EventHandler`1.Invoke(Object sender, TEventArgs e)
   at Rubberduck.Parsing.VBA.RubberduckParserState.OnStateChanged(Object requestor, ParserState state) in C:\projects\rubberduck\Rubberduck.Parsing\VBA\RubberduckParserState.cs:line 331
   at Rubberduck.Parsing.VBA.RubberduckParserState.SetStatusAndFireStateChanged(Object requestor, ParserState status) in C:\projects\rubberduck\Rubberduck.Parsing\VBA\RubberduckParserState.cs:line 559
   at Rubberduck.Parsing.VBA.ParserStateManagerBase.SetStatusAndFireStateChanged(Object requestor, ParserState status, CancellationToken token) in C:\projects\rubberduck\Rubberduck.Parsing\VBA\ParserStateManagerBase.cs:line 51
   at Rubberduck.Parsing.VBA.ParseCoordinator.ParseAllInternal(Object requestor, CancellationToken token) in C:\projects\rubberduck\Rubberduck.Parsing\VBA\ParseCoordinator.cs:line 330
   at Rubberduck.Parsing.VBA.ParseCoordinator.ParseAll(Object requestor, CancellationToken token) in C:\projects\rubberduck\Rubberduck.Parsing\VBA\ParseCoordinator.cs:line 303
2017-10-26 12:17:56.3117;INFO-2.1.1.2431;Rubberduck.Parsing.VBA.RubberduckParserState;RubberduckParserState (4) is invoking StateChanged (Error);
```

Comment: Looks like the registration of MSO.DLL is broken. Is Access 32-bit and the rest of Office 64-bit by any chance? Or was Access 2007 installed on top of a later version of Office?

Comment: The part I can't explain is how the heck RD was able to even *create* the command bar and menu items, if enabling them throws a COM exception. But the most likely cause is Access 2007 having been installed on top of, say, Office 2010+; per Microsoft, different versions *can* run side-by-side, but only if the oldest version is installed first.

Comment: Do you have other VBA hosts on that machine? Do these other VBA hosts throw the same exception? (e.g. Excel, PowerPoint, AutoCAD, SolidWorks, Sage, etc.) - I mean, we can handle that exception before it hits the `ParseCoordinator` and thus prevent throwing the whole parse task into the gutter, but if the Office API isn't letting us enable the menus, they'll remain disabled.

Comment: I do. Excel 2010 Throws the same exception. I will revise the post with that info

Comment: And I do run ONLY access 2007 side-by-side with access 2003 on this machine. Also the 2010 suite (Excel, Word, without MS Access)

Comment: Just wanted to add that Clicking the OK button in the settings window forces the Refresh Button text to update and display `Parse Error`. I will be out-of-pocket for several hours. I will follow up when I return

Comment: FWIW, I personally do not recommend doing any serious development work on multiple side-by-side installations of Office, especially between pre-2007 and 2007 & onward. I *strongly* encourage you to get a virtualization software and use virtual machines for each version if you need to support them all.

Comment: I am aware of the issues installing SBS versions of office. I am on a corporate machine, and although I do have the power to have the uninstall/reinstall performed, the red tape would be a headache I don't think I want to take on. Thank you for the attention you have given @Mat's Mug

Comment: @this Yeah, I'm not doing "Serious Development Work" at this site. I do, however do a considerable amount of one-off work for the site on a daily basis and I felt like it would be a good environment to test drive RuberDuck in

Comment: A similar issue has been opened on the Github repository: https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck/issues/4711

Answer (score 1):

## Not an answer as such, but hopefully it helps someone...

I've been using Rubberduck for some time now and (long story short) it stopped working yesterday after I unwittingly repaired Office 2010 and then embarked on a cleanup mission.

After reading comments from @Mathieu and @this I suspect the fact that the Access 2016 run-time was installed while I did the repair caused the issue (although not 100% sure). Presumable 'repairing' is a bit like changing the order of installation... ?

Other contributing factors could have been OneDrive and Skype both of which I uninstalled during the cleanup.

I ended up removing Office 2010 and installing Office 2016.

**Key Point, after uninstalling Office 2010 and installing Office 2016, Rubberduck is working again**

I was sorely tempted to reinstall Office 2010 but #TimeConstraints, your mileage may vary...

---

*Note:*

*The Rubberduck logs led me to this question, specifically class {000C0308-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed to load, basically the same as entry 4 in the OP's logs.*