# Rubberduck: not available in VBE, but loaded in Add-In-Manager

Tags: vbe, rubberduck

maybe similar to [Can not see the add in after installing rubberduck?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42538026/can-not-see-the-add-in-after-installing-rubberduck), but the answer there (the default installing instructions) does not work for me.

After Admin-Installing Rubberduck 2.1.0 or also tried with 2.1.1.2450-pre I cannot see the Add-in as menu-item or context-menu-item.

But everything expected is there (in Excel, Word, Powerpoint)
the SplashScreen at start: [SplashScreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1J1YK.png), 
the item in Add-in-Manager: [Add-In-Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNL0W.png), the keys in registry: [Registry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0sjZ.png)
but no menu of Rubberduck: [VBE-Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tc3HU.png)

my System: Win7 64 Pro (german), Office 2010 32bit (german).

when installing 2.0.13, during splash screen there comes this exception:[Exception_2.0.13](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l07iq.png) but still no log file. But in VBE the Rubberduck menu item is available

Comment: Is there a caption-less menu between 'Windows' and 'Help' menus by any chance? If not, is the Office install "clean", i.e. 2010 wasn't installed on top of some 2013 or 2016 component e.g. Access?

Comment: Okay, just got to a computer - the tag you're looking for is `<MinimumLogLevel>`, under `<GeneralSettings>`. Its value would be `0`; changing it to `1` would be trace level, `2` would be debug level, `3` info, `4` warning, `5` error, and `6` fatal - we log exceptions at error level, so any value higher than 5 wouldn't log the exception.

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46959267/1188513

Comment: @Mat'sMug: thanks for your answers!
unfortunately i cannot find the rubberduck.config file. in my %appdata%\Rubberduck folder there is only a "Logs" folder, which is empty.
in my AppData Folder there is (besides a lot of other files) the Rubberduck.dll.config which is not the file you mentioned.
So my Installation seems not to be correct? But I can't remember any Installation Error...
and no, there is no caption-less menu between 'Windows' and 'Help' and there was no Office 2013/16 Installation before.

Comment: sorry, i meant in my **ProgramData** Folder, there is the Rubberduck.dll.config file
(cannot edit the comment anymore)

Comment: Once you have that log file, you can [edit] your question to include its contents.

Comment: i tried it twice once with your config file (MinimumLogLevel=0) and once with MinimumLogLevel=1, but still there is no file in the logs folder

Comment: Ok this is ...disturbing. 2.0.13 has been around since last March, and this exception was seen exactly 0 times. hmm, might have something to do with the configuration file being from 2.1 - still blows up if you delete the configuration file prior to starting Excel?

Comment: yes, still the same Exception (without config file).
ok deleted the config file.
when i go to Rubberduck -> Settings:
(OK Button does not close the window, but stores the config file, i have to use Cancel to close the window)
restart of Excel & Rubberduck brings up the same Exception.

Comment: Can you open a new issue on the GitHub repository for this? The format would be more appropriate than an SO comment thread... thanks! With v2.1.1 scheduled next weekend, this might be a critical issue we need to fix this week. Thanks a TON for helping us diagnosing this!

Comment: GitHub issue created: https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck/issues/3538

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42538026/can-not-see-the-add-in-after-installing-rubberduck   Hope this could help